# What are the alternatives for radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, user-experience

I haven't seen any radio buttons for a long time. Are they really used anymore, and if so where are they used and who used them?

What are the best alternatives for radio button? What can you use instead of radio buttons?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you mean the browser's native radio button component (for which there are Javascript based replacements) or the concept of the radio button itself (which is timeless and not really replaceable)?

Comment: @pekka radio button means HTML radio button and i want to know that what thing can be used instead of HTML radio button. that is clear ?

Comment: Yep, they're everywhere. They're also the a bit of a pain for css. The only form element more inconsistent is the file upload input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only had to look as far as the "Settings" page on my GMail account before I found a radio button on the web.

The only other widget that provides a simple "Pick one choice from many" option in an HTML document is a `<select>` element.

You can also use multiple submit buttons for the same effect — but you submit the form at the same time, so it isn't always appropriate (although good for "Preview" or "Save" decisions).

Answer (score 5):

The alternatives to radio buttons are checkboxes and drop down boxes. Use them over the alternatives when:

- One answer must be selected
- There are three or fewer (4 at a stretch)
  possible answers

Or to give a clearer distinction for yes/no fields than a single checkbox

Comment: A combobox is not an alternative to a radio button set. It is a widget that provides a dropdown menu combined with a textbox, and HTML has no native input type that provides that. You can only get a combobox by applying JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I meant a drop down. Been working in Access all morning (stupid job!!!). Changed in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Radio buttons are still commonly used on websites.

There simply is no alternative to them, that have the same functionality with the same ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ui for example:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

It's a nice alternative if your tired of plain old radio buttons ;)

Comment: That example uses radio buttons. It just uses JavaScript to severely restyle them … and break keyboard access to them in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Directly there are no alternative for radio button. [As per my knowledge].

But You can use `images` to supplant the radio buttons. You can make them function in the same manner as the radio buttons inmost cases, and you can make them any size you want.

---

If I have a choice i surely go with using simple radio buttons rather than implementing its alternative. Radio button is very much compatible in all browser so i also suggest you to don't try for any alternative just go with what you get by default.

Comment: As long as the user has Javascript enabled.

Comment: @Karpie: yes you are right as long as javascript not disable in browser.

Answer (score -1):

as Karpie sad : "Radio buttons are still commonly used on websites" !
look at https://protect.login.yahoo.com/login/set_pref for example.
the radio buttons are standard in XHTML and HTML5.

but today, the modern design is more excepted to use checkboxes or drop down boxes.

Comment: Checkboxes only substitute for radio buttons when there are exactly two choices. Drop down menus are only a good choice when there are lots of options — otherwise the cost of having to click on the menu to see what the options are is too great.

Comment: Not really a substitute as both checkbox's can be checked, whereas usually radio buttons can't (if they are grouped)